# Return Django queryset of items that appear in a single category when items can appear in multiple categories

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to return a queryset of all items in a Category where items can occur in multiple categories.  The relevant model declarations are below along with one of many attempts that did not work.  Is there a way to do this using Django's built-in intermediate table functionality without having to explicitly declare a model for the intermediary table?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)

    def items(self):
        curr_category = Category.objects.filter(pk=self.id)
        items_in_category = curr_category.item__categories_set.all().values('item_id')
        return Item.objects.filter(pk__in=items_in_category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category,null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is with a custom `models.Manager` on your `Item` model. This is ideal, IMHO, because this logic doesn't really belong in your `Category` model. What if you want categories for things besides `Item`'s? Then you'd have to implement more retrieval methods on `Category`, bloating it.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_for_category(self, category):
        return self.filter(categories=category)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category,null=True)
    objects = ItemManager()
```

Then call this using:

```
items = Item.objects.get_for_category(category_instance)
```

If you really want to do it in a `Category` method, then why not:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    def items(self):
        # probably need to import Item model here in order to avoid
        # circular import reference
        from myapp.models import Item
        return Item.objects.filter(categories__id=self.id)
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I used your second suggestion because I only need to get the count of items within a category.  It wasn't even necessary to import the Item model.